# Transparent Activity not showing over Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS view on Android 13

Tags: android, settings, transparent

I need to show some suggestion view on setting page , I made transparent activity and it's working on all other device. First I m calling setting intent after that I m calling my transparent activity . So that my transparent is showing over my setting app. It's working on most of the device but it's not working on Samsung Android 13. I have tried with multiple intent flags but no one working as of now .please give me a suggestion why my transparent activity not showing over setting view .it's showing over my previous activity but it should be shown over setting view.